# ApplicationIconBadgeNumber set 0 does not work

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, push

why does the line "UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;" not work?
I send Push-Notification over PHP.

The Number will allways displayed by the app icon!

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    // class-level declarations
    UIWindow window;
    HomeViewController viewController;
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

        window = new CustomWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        viewController = new HomeViewController ();
        window.RootViewController = viewController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge;
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

because allowed natural numbers (n >= 1). When events count is equal 0 it's not showed

Comment: okay, but 1 is always shown by the app icon, if i start the app und close it, the 1 will not go away

Comment: to hide badge you should set 0